# Can Eclipse be installed to "C:\Program Files" on Windows 7 and be used without admin permissions?

Tags: eclipse

Can I safely install *Eclipse 4.3 - Kepler* to `C:\Program Files\Eclipse-4.3` under Windows 7 and run it from a normal user account?

Are there administrator requirements? Does Eclipse require write permission to its installation folder?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse you can just unzip and run from any user account.

Comment: This is at least not true for the Eclipse distribution Springsource Tool Suite 3.6.3 (based on Eclipse 4.4.1). It seems to need full access for updates.